# Reactjs:How to display image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my project, using input field to add and update images.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactCrop from "react-image-crop";
import "react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css";

export const Imagecrop = () => {
  const [src, setSrc] = useState(null);
  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.files[0]);
    setSrc(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
    console.log("src", src);
  };
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [crop, setCrop] = useState({ aspect: 16 / 9 });

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-6">
          <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleFileChange} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-6">
          {src && (
            <ReactCrop
              src={src}
              onImageLoded={setImage}
              crop={crop}
              onChange={setCrop}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

There are no errors.

[image]

I want to show the selected image to the second column but the file name is getting displayed here. Please give me some suggestions to fix this problem and the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-snow-fb61he?file=/src/imagecrop.js

Comment: Try not to rely on `console.log()` for checking state. State values don't update until the next render cycle

Comment: add sample in https://codesandbox.io/ for debugging is better

Comment: codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-snow-fb61he?file=/src/imagecrop.js

Comment: I think you need to study the react-image-crop [documentation](https://github.com/DominicTobias/react-image-crop#usage) closer. It does not accept a `src` prop but instead should have an `<img>` child

Comment: @Phil The issue is with the crop component usage. Duplicate answer does not solve it.

Comment: The duplicate answer solves your `console.log()` problem. Reading the documentation solves your `ReactCrop` problem so the question could have been closed as a typo anyway

Comment: @user15361826 Fixed sandbox -> https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-euclid-cfd83m